# "IP not whitelisted" for Websocket but not REST

Tags: rest, api, websocket, key

We have an IP whitelisted key.  The REST API (authenticated) works from our server.  When trying to use the Websocket API (authenticated) we get this response:

{"type":"error","message":"Sorry, you could not be authenticated: Unauthorized","reason":"IP does not match IP whitelist"}

Our IP address is correctly configured with the key.  The REST API calls are happy.  The Websocket feed returns this.

Why?

Comment: Question is in reference to GDAX/Coinbase REST API and Websocket stream.

Answer (score 0):

> Why?

It's GDAX bug with Websocket api :( Fix and Rest api work as intended.
See: https://github.com/coinbase/gdax-node/issues/201